# Optimize recurrence output

Tags: recursion

I have recurrence and I need to calculate first $N$ members of the sequence

```
ClearAll[aa];
l=3;
aa[n_, l_] := If[n <= l, 
   Quotient[n, l],
   (l + 2 (n - l) aa[n - l, l] + (n - l) (n - 1) aa[n - 1, l])/(n*(n + 1 - l))
]

Table[aa[i, l], {i, 0, 30}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

I guess it is stupid to use `Table` since its recalculate some of the members several times. How I can output all members in one pass? Can I use `RecurrenceTable` in this case and is it the quickest way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use memoization:

```
ClearAll[aa, bb];
l = 3;
n = 30;
aa[n_, l_] := If[n <= l, Quotient[n, l], (l + 2 (n - l) aa[n - l, l] + (n - l) (n - 1) aa[n - 1, l])/(n*(n +  1 - l))]
bb[n_, l_] := bb[n, l] = If[n <= l, Quotient[n, l], (l + 2 (n - l) bb[n - l, l] + (n - l) (n - 1) bb[n - 1, l])/(n*(n + 1 - l))]

Table[aa[i, l], {i, 0, n}] // AbsoluteTiming // First
Table[bb[i, l], {i, 0, n}] // AbsoluteTiming // First

(*
2.8
0.
*)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you suspect,`RecurrenceTable`is fast. I modified your function`aa`to eliminate the variable`l`, and renamed this variable to`s`to avoid confusion with the digit `1`. This is not perfect code, since I have to assume the cases`a[n=0]=0`, and`a[j]=1`for all`j>0`when`s=1`.

```
s = 3;
RecurrenceTable[
  {
   aa[n]==(s+2(n-s) aa[n-s] + (n-s) (n-1) aa[n-1])/(n*(n+1-s)),
   Apply[Sequence,Join[Thread[Equal[Array[aa,s-1],ConstantArray[0,s-1]]],{aa[s]==1}]]
  },
   aa,
   {n,1,30}]
```